# grep output from long to wide

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file of patterns and I want to return all the line numbers where the pattern was found, but in a wide format and not long/spread.
Example:

fileA.txt

```
Germany
USA
UK
```

fileB.txt

```
USA
USA
Italy
Germany
UK
UK
Canada
Canada
Germany
Australia
USA
```

I have done something like this:

```
grep -nf fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

which returned me:

```
1:USA
2:USA
4:Germany
5:UK
6:UK
9:Germany
11:USA
```

However, I want to have something like:

```
Germany 4 9
USA 1 2 11
UK 5 6
```

Comment: What should be output for a country that doesn't appear in fileB.txt?

Comment: @EdMorton I think empty values in that case I guess, my patterns are all present in fileB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ grep -n -x -F -f fileA.txt fileB.txt | datamash -s -t : -g 2 collapse 1
Germany:4,9
UK:5,6
USA:1,2,11
```

This first uses `grep` to get the lines from `fileB.txt` that exactly matches the lines in `fileA.txt`, and outputs the matching line numbers along with the lines themselves.

I'm using `-x` and `-F` in addition to the options that are used in the question. I do this to avoid reading the patterns from `fileA.txt` as regular expressions (`-F`), and to match complete lines, not substrings (`-x`).

The `datamash` utility is then parsing this as lines of `:`-delimited fields (`-t :`), sorting it (`-s`) on the second field (`-g 2`; the countries) and collapsing the first field (`collapse 1`; the line numbers) into a list for each country.

You could then obviously replace the colons and commas with tabs using `tr ':,' '\t\t'`, or with spaces in a similar way.

```
$ grep -n -x -f fileA.txt -F fileB.txt | datamash -s -t : -g 2 collapse 1 | tr ':,' '\t\t'
Germany 4       9
UK      5       6
USA     1       2       11
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR        { country[$0]= country[$0]? country[$0] FS NR: NR; next }
     ($0 in country){ print $0, country[$0] }' fileB fileA
```

or to report "count: ***0***" in case there was a countryName in fileA that doesn't appear in fileB, do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR        { country[$0]= country[$0]? country[$0] FS NR: NR; next }
     ($0 in country){ print $0, country[$0]; next } { print $0, "0" }' fileB fileA
```

Answer (score 5):

You could couple your grep command output with Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```bsh
grep -nf fileA.txt fileB.txt | \
mlr --c2n --ifs ":" --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output reorder -f 2  then \
nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs " " -f 1
```

You will have

```
Germany 4 9
USA 1 2 11
UK 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -nxFf fileA.txt you fileB.txt   \
| awk -F: '$0 = (length($2) FS $0)' \
| sort -t: -k1,1nr -k3,3 -k2,2n \
| cut -d: -f2- \
| sed -Ee '
  :a
    $!N;y/:/ /
    s/( \S+)\n(.*\1)$/ \2/
  ta
  s/([^\n]*) ([^\n]*)((\n.*)?)$/\2 \1\3/
  P;D
'
```

O/P:

```
Germany 4 9
USA 1 2 11
UK 5 6
```

Note: this requires GNU sed to be able to run as the \S and \n in char classes is used.

Answer (score 2):

Using an `awk` array, which is associative by definition, as a dictionary/map to collect the indexes and then dump all the keys and values in it (also using Kusalananda additions to the grep command):

```
$ grep -n -x -F -f fileA.txt fileB.txt \
| awk -F: '{dict[$2]=dict[$2]" "$1} END {for (key in dict) print key dict[key]}'
UK 5 6
Germany 4 9
USA 1 2 11
```